# Web scraping of 10000 urls to get the product review and price from Amazon website, getting output as NA only

Tags: python-3.x

Here is the code which I am trying to execute to get the output as product price and reviews of Amazon website, however I am getting the results in form of NA. Please review my code shown below, and advise if anything is missing?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
  
def main(URL):
    
    File = open("out.csv", "a")
  
    
    
    HEADERS = ({'User-Agent':
                ') ','Accept-Language': 'en-US, en;q=0.5'})
  
    
    webpage = requests.get(URL, headers=HEADERS)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(webpage.content, "lxml")
  
    
    try:

        title = soup.find("span", 
                          attrs={"id": 'productTitle'})
  
        
        title_value = title.string
  
        
        title_string = title_value.strip().replace(',', '')
  
    except AttributeError:
        title_string = "NA"
    print("product Title = ", title_string)
  

    File.write(f"{title_string},")
  

    try:
        price = soup.find(
            "span", attrs={'id': 'priceblock_ourprice'}).string.strip().replace(',', '')
        
    
    except AttributeError:
        price = "NA"
    print("Products price = ", price)
  
    
    File.write(f"{price},")
  
    
    try:
        rating = soup.find("i", attrs={
                           'class': 'a-icon a-icon-star a-star-4-5'}).string.strip().replace(',', '')
  
    except AttributeError:
  
        try:
            rating = soup.find(
                "span", attrs={'class': 'a-icon-alt'}).string.strip().replace(',', '')
        except:
            rating = "NA"
    print("Overall rating = ", rating)
  
    File.write(f"{rating},")
  
    try:
        review_count = soup.find(
            "span", attrs={'id': 'acrCustomerReviewText'}).string.strip().replace(',', '')
  
    except AttributeError:
        review_count = "NA"
    print("Total reviews = ", review_count)
    File.write(f"{review_count},")
  
    
    try:
        available = soup.find("div", attrs={'id': 'availability'})
        available = available.find("span")
                    .string.strip().replace(',', '')
  
    except AttributeError:
        available = "NA"
    print("Availability = ", available)
  
    
    File.write(f"{available},\n")
  
    
    File.close()
  
  
if __name__ == '__main__':
  
    file = open("url.txt", "r")
  

    for links in file.readlines():
        main(links)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have modified your code to find rating as

```
rating = soup.find('i', attrs={'class':'a-icon-star'}).get_text()
```

Likewise, you can alter other class attributes as per your requirement.

find() method returns the first matching element.

But, if you wish to find all ratings from a page, try this:

```
rating = soup.findAll('i', attrs={'class':'a-icon-star'})
for rate in rating:
    print(rate.get_text())
```

Comment: Thanks a lot let me try this.